RAM and Registers Analysis EMS3150 ECU TriCore TC1767
I extracted the firmware of an EMS3150 ECU, TC1767 chip.
I analysed the binary with the help of a hex editor and the TC1767 manual.
I managed to successfully load the binary in IDA Pro, with correct memory mapping, and began the disassemble process.
I identified code and data parts, and I'm now analysing functions and routines with x-refs to get a clue of how things works.
The goal is to inject some custom code to implement features like 2-step, ignition map switching, etc.
My primary target is the Dwell time map, which I want to load from a free space of PFlash I rewrited.
However, i'm facing an issue which make the process really slow and hard for the brain : I don't know how to "run" the firmware to debug it in real time. For example, I would love to see RAM addressing, step by step, to understand how things are handled. Same for registers : I would love to follow an execution of the routines with some defined values to see how functions and routines are handling the data.
I don't have access to RAM mapping for this firmware.
Question is : how can I "emulate" the firmware or parts of the firmware to debug it and see how data is handled by the program ?
Thanks

You might be able to use the Trace32 simulator:
https://gist.github.com/patois/4d32ac437f32682b49f3480569ae0ec6
